# Populate multiple tables with data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm trying to populate multiple tables from mysql, ordering them by an id.  I'm not sure how to do this and can't find much on it on here.

At the moment I am populating just one table from mysql but I've added a new column to my mysql table, which would be the specific id for each table - not sure how to loop this though.

In the predictions table I have a column called 'accid' . I'd like this column to group together a set of results with the same 'accid' and insert into an html table. How do I do this?

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT results.home_team, results.away_team, results.home_id,    
       results.away_id, results.ht_score, results.ft_score, predictions.draw,    
       predictions.winningid 
          FROM results 
              LEFT JOIN predictions ON results.match_id = predictions.matchid 
          WHERE userid='".$_SESSION['id']."' ORDER BY home_team");

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);   

    if($num_rows) {
    $wonBet = true;  #ADDED
    $notlong = false;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        if(!$row["ht_score"]) {
            $halftime = "-";
        } else {
            $halftime = $row["ht_score"];
        }
        if(!$row["ft_score"]) {
            $fulltime = "-";
        } else {
            $fulltime = $row["ft_score"];
        }

        echo "<td>" . $row["home_team"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . " vs " . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row["away_team"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $halftime . "</td>" . "<td>" . $fulltime . "</td>";



        $value = $fulltime;
        $apart = explode('-',$value); 
        if($apart[0] > $apart[1] && $row["home_id"]==$row["winningid"]) {
            $hometeamwin = "Win";

        } else if($apart[0] < $apart[1] && $row["away_id"]==$row["winningid"]) {
            $hometeamwin = "Win"; 

        } else if($apart[0] == $apart[1] && !$row["winningid"]) {
            $hometeamwin = "Win"; 

        } else { 
            $hometeamwin = "lose";
               #ADDED 

        }



        if($fulltime!=$row["ft_score"]) {
             $hometeamwin = ""; 
             }

             if($hometeamwin == "lose"){   #ADDED
            $wonBet = false;         #ADDED
        } 

             if($hometeamwin == ""){   #ADDED
            $notlong = true;         #ADDED
        }       


        echo "<td>" . $hometeamwin . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Im not clear on what you are asking for.

Comment: how would I populate multiple tables with data from mysql rather than just one table?

Comment: Fetch your results into an array - then loop as many times as you want.

Comment: would you be able to display as an answer please?

Comment: `mysql_` library for MySQL database queries is deprecated. Choose a newer API for new projects. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: thanks @PhilipWhitehouse I'm bit of a noob with mysql so I've just started out on the older library - I will change it over though

Comment: `mysqli` can be used in a procedural style (but you should learn OOP PHP asap).

Answer (score 0):

To use the same query results more than once, fetch them into an array. Then you can loop as many times as you want over the same results.

Oh - and switch to PDO / MySQLi. .. and use prepared statements..

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT results.home_team, results.away_team, results.home_id,    
   results.away_id, results.ht_score, results.ft_score, predictions.draw,    
   predictions.winningid 
      FROM results 
          LEFT JOIN predictions ON results.match_id = predictions.matchid 
      WHERE userid='".$_SESSION['id']."' ORDER BY home_team");
while($dbrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $data[] = $dbrow;
}

foreach($data as $row) {
   //Table

}

foreach($data as $row) {
   //Table 2

}
```

Some ideas about splitting by accid

```
while($dbrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $accid = $dbrow['accid'];
     $data[$accid][] = $dbrow;
}
foreach($data as $accid -> rows) {
  //Table Header
  foreach($rows as $row) {
   //Table Row        
  }
  //Table Footer
}
```

Comment: thanks for this - what if the data I'm selecting will be different depending on one column - and that column will be the id for tables. Say if I have 4 rows with 'accid' column '412' and 5 rows with 'accid' column '413' - what would I need to do?

Comment: actually I could just use an if statement, couldn't I?

Comment: You seem to be confusing 'id' with PRIMARY key or some other term. But yes you can probably use an if statement..

Comment: Looking at it again, I don't think I'd be able to use foreach as I don't know how many tables there will be? As I say it depends on that one column in mysql

Comment: foreach loops round a single SQL result, with one output for each row. What do you actually mean by 'multiple tables'. Are you confusing rows and tables.

Comment: I'm not 'accid' is a column within my mysql table where each option from a form is givin the same value.

Comment: You can put a foreach in another loop.. If you restate your question (accid isn't mentioned currently), I could update my answer.

Comment: I'm confused...Because in your answer above - you are defining the tables with a foreach loop, where I'd like the mysql to determine how many html tables there are. for example: If there are 4 results with 'accid' = 12 (That would be 1 table) If there was another 4 results with 'accid' = 24 (that would be another table)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21960/discussion-between-philip-whitehouse-and-andrew-charlton)